# Does elementary OS use the standard AppIndicators?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I think about switching from Ubuntu, but I don't want to miss the AppIndicators.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it does: http://elementaryos.org/docs/user-guide/learn-basics/desktop

Answer (score 0):

It does, they were introduced in Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat, I believe (maybe even 10.04 Lucid Lynx). And that's what Elementary OS 0.1 Jupiter is based on.
+ I can confirm that as I'm using Elementary OS myself :p